# How to use delete query for sql database in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to delete a row corresponding to a particular IP address ..
I have written this query :

```
  string dlt = @"DELETE [LocationIP], [LocationName],[LocationID],
                [NoOfUsers],[MinutesUsed] FROM [LocationInfo] WHERE LocationIP=@ipadd";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dlt, sqlcon_QOEMetrices);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ipadd", SqlDbType.NChar, 15);

  cmd.Parameters["@ipadd"].Value = ipadd;
```

where ip address is stored in the string variable ipadd
This query is not showing any result but even not giving any error...

Answer (score 3):

You need to [*execute*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) your command.

Something like:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: @johntotetwoo - Thanks for the correction. You could have edited that yourself, you know :)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - as did I... but within the grace period, so we will never know who got it first...

Comment: @Oded lol guessing you did otherwise my name would be up there under the edit history I think.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the execution of your query?

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong, you don't want a select list in a `DELETE` statement.

```
string dlt = @"DELETE FROM [LocationInfo] WHERE LocationIP=@ipadd";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dlt, sqlcon_QOEMetrices);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ipadd", SqlDbType.NChar, 15);
```

would suffice. I then assume you are doing somthing like

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this simple query and execute,

```
 "DELETE FROM LocationInfo WHERE LocationIP=@ipadd"

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dlt, sqlcon_QOEMetrices);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ipadd", SqlDbType.NChar, 15);

  cmd.Parameters["@ipadd"].Value = ipadd;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You need to learn about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Concatenating SQL is not a good idea from a security point of view.

Comment: The code the OP posted is actually much better in this regard.

Comment: Then perhaps you should _delete_ this answer, as it is showing a _bad_ practice?